# Sticky navigation slide down on scroll. Issue with slide up

Tags: jquery, scroll, navigation, sticky

I'm trying to make the navigation sticky on scroll without the use of heavy plugins for such a  small thing.

Here's the code till now:

```
        var menuOffset = $('#nav-wrap')[0].offsetTop; 
        $(document).bind('ready scroll', function() {
            var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (docScroll > 300) {
                if (!$('#nav-wrap').hasClass('sticky')) {
                    $('#nav-wrap').addClass('sticky').css({
                        top: '-80px'
                    }).stop().animate({
                        top: 0
                    }, 500);
                }
            } else {

                    $('#nav-wrap').removeClass('sticky').removeAttr('style');
            }

        });
```

Works almost fine, although I need the #nav-wrap to slide back up before removing the class 'sticky' and the static navigation gets back in place (and in the browser viewport), as I don't like how it jumps back in place. Any advice?

http://jsfiddle.net/D8V7b/60/

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a jSFiddle? It's hard to work out what you are describing

Comment: Sure, question updated. Basically I want the sticky-nav to slide up before the original navigation gets back into the viewport

Answer (score 0):

I assume in your real scenario you can't just use css position fixed to achieve this.

It seems like you are waiting too long to activate the stickyness, try making it kick in when the document's scrollTop is only 20, for example, not 300 as in your code.

```
var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
            if (docScroll > 20) { ...
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JvnwY/

Comment: Thanks. It's not that though. Problem is that the sticky nav have a different width then the static one, and it's not a the very top either.

Hence I need the sticky nav to slide back up before the original nav gets back into the viewport, let's say when it's 400px from the top for instance.
Sorry I don't how to explain it better